# preg_replace php remove leading numbers then stop after the period

Tags: php, regex

I have this strings. i want to remove the "0002." but it also remove the 22. How will i remove the leading numbers and the dot(.) then stop removing any numbers after?

```
$title = "0002.22 Greatest Voices In The Business (Current Female Singers Only)";
$words = preg_replace('/[0-9]+./', '', $title );
```

output:

```
Greatest Voices In The Business (Current Female Singers Only)
```

expected output:

```
22 Greatest Voices In The Business (Current Female Singers Only)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you need to remove all numbers from start of the string till the dot ?
Use `^` for "start of string"

```
$title = "0002.22 Greatest Voices In The Business (Current Female Singers Only)";
$words = preg_replace('/^[0-9]+\./', '', $title );
```

If u need to remove any number followed by dot, your code is correct, except that **dot** is special character and need to be escaped .

```
$title = "0002.22 Greatest Voices In The Business (Current Female Singers Only)";
$words = preg_replace('/[0-9]+\./', '', $title );
```